# Solidity - size limit on arrays

Tags: arrays, ethereum, solidity

I need to pass in an array of 1,000 integers to my Solidity contract.

The integers will all have values between 0 and 1000 (meaning none of the values will be less than 0 or greater than 1,000.)

My simple question is this then: in terms of block-sizes and gas-fees, can Solidity/Ethereum handle this sort of operation - or am I asking for trouble here by pushing it too hard?

With that comes the question of: how do I properly test this?
Will deploying my contract on Rinkeby and testing this out there suffice - or will that nor really give me a true picture of what might happen on mainnet?

Finally, what if I wanted to pass-in an array of 1,000 Ethereum **ADDRESSES**?
Is that a whole different ballgame in terms of memory requirements, or can Solidity/Ethereum handle that?

Would appreciate any and all tips on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum virtual machine global state is currently several hundred gigabytes, passing 1,000 addresses does not have any meaningful impact.

Whatever the transaction cost of writing such data to a blockchain is a business question and cannot be answered on a programmer forum.

Transaction cost can be reliably estimated e.g. by using unit testing and recording gas cost of transactions in the test suite.

Comment: I see - and I should have been clearer: I did not mean this as a business question as gas fees are not an issue for us. So it’s strictly a technical “is it possible?” type of question.  Meaning, is it possible to pass 1,000 int values or 1,000 ETH Address values into a contract in a *single* transaction - or is that too much data for one transaction? That is my question. (We aren't well versed in Solidity/Ethereum and don’t know enough about how Blocks are mined but we hear there are some size limitations. That’s why we’re asking.)

Comment: Even if you could do it in one transaction, I would advise not to. Why not just split it to smaller batches and not discuss about arbitrary 1,000 int values nubmer.

Comment: There's nothing "arbitrary" about the 1,000 values I inquired about. That IS the actual number of values we need to pass: 1,000.  I specified that quite clearly in the opening sentence of my question. And of course, we can break it up into 4 x 250, or 5 x 200, etc. - but if there's no real need to do that, why do it?

This is what this question has been all about: trying to get an idea of the scope/scale/bandwidth/capabilities. You alluded to a "test suite" but didn't make any suggestions for something specific - which would have been more helpful. 
All good, we'll figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: There is no suggestion to any specific because the question does not have anything specific (code, frameworks, etc.)

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa
I am not sure why you said there is nothing specific, the question is already as specific as can be.

Comment: It does not include details like why you need to pass the array and what is the content of the array. It might be that you do not need that large array in the first place. See https://xyproblem.info/